# Sockets Xamarin Android

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, socket

Quería preguntarles, sí ¿Xamarin Android soporta System.Net.Sockets'?

Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera(este es una partecita del codigo)

```
IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.4");
     // use local m/c IP address, and 
     // use the same in the client
/* Initializes the Listener */
    TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,5555);

/* Start Listeneting at the specified port */        
    myList.Start();
```

Pero la aplicación en el celular se cierra inesperadamente.

Me ayudan por favor, se los agradecería.

Comment: Si son soportados, el error debe de ser por otro lado. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.Sockets.Socket/

Comment: Te recomiendo que pruebes estos componentes: - Sockets Plugin: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/rda.socketsforpcl - Websockets.PCL: https://github.com/NVentimiglia/Websockets.PCL

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar bro?

Answer (score 0):

En tu aplicación Android necesitas modificar el Android Manifest y habilitar el permiso de INTERNET para que los sockets funcionen.

[image: Propiedades de projecto Xamarin]

De otra forma la aplicación estara cerrandose espontaneamente a la hora de inicializar el socket.